# RabbitMQ creating idle queues having no consumers

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

**Problems**

1. High Memory Usage
2. Blocked Workers
3. High Number of channels and Connections
4. Blocked Connections
   Deployment
   `Aws EKS`
   I have a Django application and have long-running tasks implemented in celery with RabbitMQ as a Message broker and Result Backend.
   Over time it uses More memory and connections are getting blocked, when I inspected I found that celery workers are not able to get tasks from rabbitmq.
   I had logged in to the celery pod which was already running celery worker with the command:
    `celery -A app_name worker -l info`.
    I Logged in to pod and started workers with the same command and it started to consume tasks
   I understand connections are blocked if we have high memory usage.
   While debugging I checked I have a lot of random queues(1380 queues) without consumers ready to deliver messages and  unpack messages, a large number of connections around 800, a large number of channels, and unused references(I had to clean up using rabbitmqctl force_gc then it started to work)
   but I am not able to replicate this scenario in my localhost.
   In my localhost when I start workers some temporary event queues are created and they destroy as soon as the worker stops, I had tried with the cold shutdown of celery workers as well but was not able to replicate this.
   I want to consume all messages in the queue if it has ready to deliver messages.
   As per the doc, even in case of exceptions messages should have been acknowledged but I don't know why we have a lot of unacknowledged messages
   As of now I have set the expiry to the queues and have added
    `--without-mingle and --without-gossip` parameters.
   I want a permanent fix of these idle queues

```
Celery Configuration
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

RabbitMq policies

```
Pattern :   
Apply to:   all
Definition  
ha-mode:    all
ha-sync-mode:   automatic
Priority    0 (edited)
```

[image]
[image] to execute tasks that are sent to it,